# How can I modify my css or cshtml to obtain a dropdown navbar similar to the one on w3school?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to make the same menu as on https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar.

However I would like to genereated the menu in the cshtml file here is what my menu looks like so far.
[image: My menu]

Here is my modified css

```
.main-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    display: flex;
}

.parent-menu {
    float: left;
}

    li a, .menu-dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.parent-menu a:hover, .menu-li-dropdown:hover .menu-dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    li.menu-li-dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }

.dropdown-menu-content {
    clear: both;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

    .dropdown-menu-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

        .dropdown-menu-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

.menu-li-dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is how I generate the html

```
@helper GetTreeMenus(IEnumerable<erp_colombia.Models.MenuMaster> siteMenu, Nullable<int> parentID)
    {
        foreach (var i in siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(parentID)))
        {
            var submenu = siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(i.MenuID)).Count();

            string action = i.ActionName;
            string controller = i.ControllerName;

            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="/@i.ControllerName/@i.ActionName">
                        @i.MenuText
                    </a>
                </li>
                @GetTreeMenus(siteMenu, i.MenuID)
            </ul>
        }
    }
@{
    if (Session["MenuList"] != null)
    {
        <ul class="main-menu">
            @GetTreeMenus(Session["MenuList"] as IEnumerable<erp_colombia.Models.MenuMaster>, 0)
        </ul>
    }
}
```

And here is part of my generated html.

```
<ul class="main-menu">
                                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="/Acceuil/Index">
                            Menú principal
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="//">
                            Técnico
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="//">
                            Modulo técnico
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li class="treeview">
                        <a href="//">
                            Contrato técnico
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

What must I change in my css or cshtml to obtain the same result as on w3school.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, I didn't understand your question but now that I read It twice I do, try to add display: flex to your main-menu class:

```
.main-menu {
    display: flex;
}
```

This should put the main-menu's li all in a row, Let me know if this works...

Comment: Yes it is part of what i need however I would also like when my mouse hovers over the parent menu that the sub elements appear under it like on w3 school. But now my menu is horizontal thanks to you.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach this should be easy let me make a complete answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS as it is in W3Schools

```
 <style>
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
      float: left;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: red;
    }

    li.dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
```

Here i altered you `html` as below

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Test1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"> Menú principal</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Test2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Técnico</a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Test3</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Modulo técnico</a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Test4</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Contrato técnico</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the over effect You can do It without javascript, this example is pretty unstiled so don't look at that you can adjust It after:

```css
/*Put grey background and put all parents divs in a row*/
.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
 }
 
 .main-menu div a {
   margin: 20px;
 }
 
 .main-menu div div p {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 30px;
 }
 
 
 /*Hide the children divs*/
 .main-menu div div {
  display: none;
 }
  
 .main-menu div:hover div {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <div>
    <a href="#fruits">Fruits</a>
    <div id="fruits">
      <p>Apple</p>
      <p>Mango</p>
      <p>Orange</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <a href="#vegetables">vegetables</a>
    <div id="vegetables">
      <p>Gabbage</p>
      <p>Tomatoes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem is I dont know how to modifie the cshtml file to generate the html that you are suggesting.